# Extract URL in PHP

Tags: php, apache, url

I want to create a command line tool for web. something similar to the website futz[dot]me.

I want users to enter in their addressbar : mydomain.com/anytext

& want to extract "anytext" in PHP. How can I do this??

I tried this using HTTP Referrer but getting 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

From PHP documentation: [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/parse_url)

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Comment: Thanks $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] did the job!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using mod_rewrite and it would essentially pass it off as a regular parameter